# How to replace certain symbols from the whole text except quoted text with REGEX

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a variable `text` like this:

"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet; consetetur sadipscing elitr; sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor **"invidunt; ut labore"** et dolore magna aliquyam erat/ sed diam voluptua."

What I would like to do is replace all symbols from an array:

```
var symbolsToreplace = [';', '/', '.']
```

to a comma. Also What I would like to do is NOT to replace anything within quotes, so all symbols stay the same.
Here is Regex to detect quotes:

```
var detectQuotes = /"([^"]*)"/g;
```

For now I have achieved one part of task (here I replace all the symbols from an array to ','):

```
  symbolsToreplace.map(function (s) {
    if(text.indexOf(s) !== -1 ) {
      text.replace(s, ',');
    }
  })
```

How could I apply the Regex `detectQuotes`, so thre symbols inside the quotes will be ignored?

Comment: `.replace(/"([^"]*)"|[;.\/]/g, function($0,$1) { return $1 ? $0 : ',';})`

Answer (score 2):

You could split a text by a double quote, then apply replacement only for odd fragments, and then concatenate results:

```js
var text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet; consetetur sadipscing elitr; sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor \"invidunt; ut labore\" et dolore magna aliquyam erat/ sed diam voluptua.";
var delimiters = ';./',
  template = new RegExp('[' + delimiters + ']','g')

var replaced = text
  .split('"')
  .reduce(function(previous, current, index) {
    current = (index % 2 === 0) ? current.replace(template, ',') : current;
    return previous + '"' + current;
  }, '');

console.log(replaced);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use a `replace` method with the regex that will capture the substring between double quotes and only match the chars you want to replace, then check inside the anonymous method if Group 1 matched, and if yes, restore the match, else, replace it with the comma:

```js
var s = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet; consetetur sadipscing elitr; sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor "invidunt; ut labore" et dolore magna aliquyam erat/ sed diam voluptua.';
console.log(
    s.replace(/"([^"]+)"|[;.\/]/g, function($0,$1) { return $1 ? $0 : ',';})
    // ES6:
    //s.replace(/"([^"]+)"|[;.\/]/g, ($0,$1) => $1 ? $0 : ',')
);
```

**Details**

- `"([^"]+)"` - matches a `"`, then captures into Group 1 any one or more chars other than  `"` and then matches a `"`
- `|` - or
- `[;.\/]` - a `;`, `.` or `/` char
- `function($0,$1) { return $1 ? $0 : ',';}` - assign the whole match to `$0` and the captured substring to `$1`. If `$1` is not empty, replace with the whole match, else, replace with `,`.